# Disallowing POST requests from different origins GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to stop requests (POSTs) from different origins on Google App Engine? I understand that IP spoofing is "easy", is there another solution, maybe sessions? Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure from your wording if this is the answer you're after, but you can get the referrer page using the following:

```
    #Get referring page
    referer = self.request.environ['HTTP_REFERER'] \
              if 'HTTP_REFERER' in self.request.environ else  None
```

You can then use regex to decided whether to process the request further. Source: http://blog.andrewhays.net/how-to-get-the-referer-url-from-google-appeng

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this is PHP, just check `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` for the IP/`$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` for host they are connecting from. For your specific question though, I would reccomend creating a SESSION variable for when data is submitted it can be checked by the server to verify its source. You can read more on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172739/validate-origin-of-form-post-to-ensure-it-came-from-same-server-app).

Hope this helps and DFTBA. :)

Comment: Sorry to give you a down vote. It's not PHP, it's running on Google's App Engine so it would be either Python or Java (Python in this case). Furthermore I specified that spoofing an IP address is easy, so `REMOTE_ADDR` isn't a safe way to determine where are user is coming from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773969/is-it-safe-to-trust-serverremote-addr